# Angular: using a pub/sub pattern with $q

Tags: angularjs, publish-subscribe

Is it possible to implement a pub/sub with Angular using $q this way?

```
 // publish method
 var promises = [];

 while (index--) {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  defer.resolve( subscribers[index].func(args || {}) );
  promises.push(defer);
 }

 return $q.all(promises);
```

**Edit:** So, after some searching on stack overflow, the pub/sub pattern is probably NOT the right way to handle promises...

**Edit edit** removed a non-functional implementation.

Comment: What you've written works in a different way from what you expect,  I guess. `func` is called for each subscriber immediately. Not when `$q.all` is called. And also there is a mistake in pushing deferred instead of a promise

Comment: Why would you use promises for notifications?

Comment: AngularJS already implemented the pub/sub pattern with `$broadcast/$emit/$on` in `$scope`

Comment: @HuyHoangPham I realize this but pub/sub is (for me) actually an easier mental model. I just have to `Service.subscribe` or `Service.publish` and I don't have to think about going up or down the scope chain.